# Cargar elemento con ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con ajax y php y estoy teniendo un problema.

Procedo a comentarlo:

Tengo una página `antecedentes.php` la cual tiene un botón agregar categorías, el cual llama a la función en ajax agregar categorías.

La función me agrega la cateogoría pero el tema es, que cuando recibe los datos, necesito que cargue en `.load` la página **`antecedentes.php` + `la variable de usuario`** que creó esa categoría, ya que tengo una consulta SQL en `antecedentes.php` que me lista las categorías según el `idpersona`.

El código de la función esta así:

```
function agregardatoscategoria(idpersona,nombre,descripcion){

cadena="idpersona=" + idpersona + 
        "&nombre=" + nombre +
        "&descripcion=" + descripcion;


        $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"php/agregarDatosCategoria.php",
    data:cadena,
    success:function(r){
        if(r==1){
            $('').load('antecedentes.php');

            alertify.success("agregado con exito :)");
        }else{
            alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
        }
    }
});
```

En `.load` tendría que cargar `antecedentes.php?id=idpersona` pero no se como pasar la variable.

Espero alguna respuestas y haber planteado bien mi pregunta. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchísimas gracias por su colaboración. Con load me estaba complicando, logre solucionar lo que queria de esta manera.

```
 window.location.replace("antecedentes.php?id="+idpersona);
```

Agradezco el altruismo de la comunidad! Salu2!!

Answer (score 0):

Debería bastar con enviar el parámetro en la URL, así:

```
$('#contenedor').load('antecedentes.php?id='+idpersona);
```

Comment: Hola Piyin, gracias por tu comentario, pero sigue sin cargarme :-(. El mensaje de alertify me sale como que agrego y si recargo la pagina me aparecen los resultados. Pero cuando termina la funcion no me aparece. sera que en $('') tendria que ir algo?

Comment: Tienes razón, copié tu código sin detenerme a pensarlo realmente. `.load` se debe llamar sobre un elemento que exista en la página. Por ejemplo: `$('#resultado')`

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas la documentación de JQuery [Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) verás que la función recibe 3 parámetros: url, data y la función que ejecute una vez se complete la carga. Entonces la variable deberías enviarla en el segundo parámetro, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
 $('').load('antecedentes.php', {id: persona});
```

Luego en antecedentes.php puedes capturar la variable de la siguiente forma:

```
idPersona = $_POST['id'];
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: gracias lucas por tu ayuda, el tema es que en el momento de lanzar la función yo ya estoy tomando el idpersona desde $_GET  (antecedentes.php?id=x), el tema es q que quiero que cuando termine de hacer la función de agregar categoría me cargue los valores agregados. SI le paso a la consulta la variable por POST me va a tomar error por que no esta definida esa variable.